# Why is $[-1,1]$ compact when $a_n = (-1)^k$ does not converge in $A$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I know this question sounds silly but I was reading the definition of compactness and couldn't quite wrap my head around this

Compactness :A subset $A$ of a metric space $M$ is compact if every sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ has a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ that converges to a limit in $A$

- Let $A = [-1,1]$, then a sequence in $A$ is $a_n = (-1)^k$ which
  oscillates between $-1$ and $1$

  Any sequence is a subsequence of itself

  $a_n = (-1)^k$ does not converge in $A$, therefore $A$ is not compact

Can someone point out my error please!

Comment: Compactness means that there is a convergent subsequence. It doesn't mean every subsequence is convergent.

Comment: _Has_ a subsequence! You've shown that sequence has a divergent subsequuence. That's irrelevant - the question is whether it _also_ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: You have only shown that one particular subsequence does not have a limit. However, clearly the even terms form a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not silly question. The part you didn't understand is:  "has a subsequence"= "has at least one" - that means it is enough to have just one subsequence that converges in $A$, for example $a_{2k}$ but all others don't have to converge, for example sequence $a_k$ as subsequence itself.

Maybe counterexample will help you to understand more:

You can use  the same theorem to prove that $B=\langle0,1]$ is not compact since $b_n=(\frac{1}{n})$ is sequence in $B$ which is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ with limit $0$. And you know that every subsequence of convergent sequence has the same limit, $0$ in this  case, and since $0\notin B$ there is no subsequence of $b_n$ that converges in $B$ so $B$ is not compact.

Answer (score 6):

Every sequence needs to have a converging subsequence but not every subsequence needs to converge. In your case obviously $a_{2k}$ converges which is sufficient to see that the sequence is no counter example.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the quantifiers. It says that for every sequence ($\forall$), there exists ($\exists)$ a subsequence which converges.

That means in your space, pick any arbitrary sequence. Then if the space is compact, there should exist *one* (or more) convergent subsequences. Contrast with saying for every sequence and every subsequence of the sequence converges.

In your example, you've picked $((-1)^k)$ so what is the converging subsequence? In fact, you can find more than one: by taking $k$ to be just even or just odd, then the subsequences will be constant at $1$ and $-1$ respectively.